# Avoid same value in parameter argument in object

Tags: java, oop, object, parameters, arguments

Suppose I create an object in Java like this

```
Student std1 = new Student("Tom", "male");
```

I need to prevent another object(such: std2, std3, etc) to have same value as std1. How to do it?

[edit] The example of what I want is:

**disallowed:** `Student std2 = new Student("Tom", "male");`

**allowed:** `Student std2 = new Student("Not Tom", "male");` or `Student std2 = new Student("Tom", "female");` or `Student std2 = new Student("John", "male");`, etc

Thanks

Comment: No, you do not need that / should do that. What you may want is to disallow a second `Student` instance with the same data to be persisted or added to a `Course` or whatever, **but** you should **not** disallow the creation of the object itself.

Comment: is `new Student("Tom", "female")` or `new Student("Not Tom", "male")` allowed? It's not clear what you meant by "the same value"...

Comment: I think you need an Embedded ID. If you try to create an object with duplicate values, it would not be allowed.

Comment: You can create a static String HashSet by adding a concatenated name,gender to it. So the data in your HashSet will look like `Tom,male` , `Tom,female`, `John,male`.

And in the parameterized constructor of your Student class, you can check the HashSet if that doesn't  have Name,Gender in it, and then instantiate and object.

Something like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a static String HashSet by adding a concatenated name,gender to it.

```
class YourClass {
   public static Set<String> studentSet = new HashSet<>();

   public static void addStudent(String name, String gender) {
     YourClass.studentSet.add(name + "," + gender);
   }

   public static Boolean studentExists(String name, String gender) {
     return YourClass.studentSet.constains(name + "," + gender);
}
```

So the data in your HashSet will look like Tom,male , Tom,female, John,male.

```
class Student {
...

public Student(String name, String gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    YourClass.addStudent(name, gender);
  }
}
```

And while creating an instance of Student you can check the HashSet if that doesn't have Name,Gender in it, and then instantiate and object.

```
if(!YourClass.studentExists(name, gender)) {
    Student student = new Student(name, gender);
}
```

I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that will control creation of the object - basically use a flyweight pattern.

Step 1. Make the constructor of Student package-private

```
public class Student {
    Student(String name, String gender) {
    ...
```

Step 2. Implement equals method in Student

```
   public boolean equals (Object other) {
       if (!(other instanceof Student)) return false;
       Student otherStudent = (Student) other;
       return Objects.equals(otherStudent.getName(), this.getName()) && Objects.equals(otherStudent.getGender(), this.getGender());
   }
```

Step 3. Implement a pool of Student objects in the same package

```
public class StudentPool {
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public Student getOrCreate(String name, String gender) {
        Student student = new Student(name, gender);
        return students.stream()
                .filter(s -> Objects.equals(s, student))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    students.add(student);
                    return student;
                });
    }

    public List<Student> get(String name) {
        return students.stream()
                .filter(student -> Objects.equals(student.getName(), name))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the OP wants name + gender combination to be unique (not only the name), you need to create a key combining both those values rather than using the name as the key

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "value" you are referring to the students´ name, I´d suggest that you write a little function that will return true if the name is already taken. To do this, you can store all of your "students" in an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Now you can add students to this ArrayList like the following:

```
private boolean nameIsAlreadyTaken(ArrayList<Student> students, String newName){
    for (int i = 0; i < student.size(); i++){
        if(students.get(i).getName().equals(newName)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(You need to define a getName()-function in the student-class for this to work.)

then you can do something like this:

String newName = "Michael";
String newGender = "male";

```
if (!nameIsAlreadyTaken(students, newName)){
students.add(new Student(newName, newGender));
} else{
    //something you want to to if the name is already taken
}
```

You can do this without passing the students-ArrayList to the function, but this is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need to override `Student`'s `equals` and `hashCode` methods, and then check in constructor if such a student exists. Good answer on this point: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/7643283).

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
    private static final Set<Student> REGISTERED_STUDENTS = new HashSet<>();

    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public static Collection<Student> getRegisteredStudents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(REGISTERED_STUDENTS);
    }

    public Student(final String name, final String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;

        if (REGISTERED_STUDENTS.contains(this))
            throw DuplicateStudentException();

        REGISTERED_STUDENTS.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, gender);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Student)) return false;
        final Student student = (Student) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, student.name) && Objects.equals(gender, student.gender);
    }
}
```

Please, note that this example is not thread-safe and uses arguable solution of throwing exception right in the constructor. Probably you will want a factory method and `ConcurrentSkipListSet` or another thread-safe collection, like this:

```java
class Student {
    private static final Set<Student> REGISTERED_STUDENTS = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getGender));

    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public static Set<Student> getRegisteredStudents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(REGISTERED_STUDENTS);
    }

    public static void addStudent(final String name, final String gender) {
        Student probablyExists = new Student(name, gender);
        REGISTERED_STUDENTS.add(probablyExists);
    }

    private Student(final String name, final String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, gender);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Student)) return false;
        final Student student = (Student) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, student.name) && Objects.equals(gender, student.gender);
    }
}
```